Are my new intraindividual variability statistics sensical?
UPDATE
In response to both of you: First, thank you for your responses. I wanted to clarify things about the threshold and provide some background. The peripheral blood eosinophil count (PBEC) is thought of as a measure of “eosinophilic” someone’s asthma is. In uncontrolled asthma, we can prescribe these new drugs to better control the asthma, but we’re not really sure who they’re good for (and these drugs are extremely expensive at >$35,000/year). Our best guess is that patients with a high PBEC are the best responders to the drugs, but there are still partial responders and non-responders to these drugs despite an elevated PBEC. My hypothesis is that the single PBEC used to decide whether to prescribe for some patients is just an outlier. I wanted to quantify how often these outliers occur (Probability of threshold stability) and also provide clinicians a sense of how likely the next value will be consistent with the current measurement (probability of change over threshold).
In response to EdM: These are made every time a patient has a visit, which is at variable intervals between the patients. On average, these measurements occur about once a year. Additionally, regarding the second threshold: these are prescription thresholds for different drugs. Drug A requires the patient to have a PBEC > 150 cells/ul while drug B requires the patient to have a PBEC > 300 cells/ul. There are subtle reasons why you pick one drug over another, but in either case you need elevated PBEC.  Finally, great point. we carefully excluded values that could have been affected by clinical interventions. Most clinical interventions that affect PBEC levels are transient, and involve prescription of another, different class of drug (corticosteroids). Overall, this should represent the "natural history" of the PBEC, i.e. how it varies absent clinical intervention.
In response to Michael Lew: So overall our goal is to demonstrate that a single measurement may be unreliable - that is to say, sometimes its possible to obtain a measurement below the threshold and then subsequently obtain a measurement above the threshold and vice versa. The current wisdom is that once you obtain a measurement above one of the thresholds, you are permanently above that threshold. Indeed we try to demonstrate that it is possible to obtain a value above the threshold as an initial value (indicating you should prescribe a drug), and then subsequently never be above that threshold with repeat measurements. As mentioned above, we carefully excluded values affected by subsequent interventions. And you're exactly correct about a second measurement. We are going to use our figures here to argue that adding a second measurement would more robustly classify patients as above the threshold than a single measurement.
Original Post
I'm working on a project where I'm evaluating the intra-individual variability of a biomarker (called the PBEC, or Peripheral Blood Eosinophil Count). In particular, we are interested in how often this biomarker crosses a pre-determined, clinically relevant threshold (strictly speaking there are two thresholds of interest here). I couldn't find a lot of resources on previous research in this, so I tried to get creative. I modified the Probability of Acute Change, commonly used in the psychometric research, in two different ways to fit my research question. First I calculated the frequency that someone's first value would be greater than the threshold, and then never again above the threshold after several measurements. To do this, a patient was given a score of 1 if they had a value greater than threshold other than their initial value. I then aggregated everyone who had an initial value within a range, and took the looked at the proportion of patients in that range that would eventually produce at least one value greater than the threshold. I called this the probability of threshold stability. There is importance in the first value, since clinical decisions may be made solely based on this first measurement.
Then I calculated probability the n+1 observation would be greater than the predefined threshold for a given value at the nth observation. I called this the probability of change over threshold. I show the graphs I made below, as well as sample data and the R code I used to generate the figures.
I have a few questions about these statistics.

do they make sense? I.e., if you came across these in a publication would you be highly skeptical of their utility or do they add help with my goal of quantifying IIV across a cutoff?
Have I re-invented something already made? Is there a paper I can cite that does something substantially similar?
Is there a better name for these?
I've also attempted to formalize these in mathematical terms, but I'm not so good at that. my best shot is below (I don't know how to write mathematical equations in this box, so its a photo).




Here is modified (d/t HIPAA concerns) data with the code for reproducing the figures.
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

meanlog <- 1  
sdlog <- 1    
N <- 100  
data_matrix <- matrix(rlnorm(N * 50, exp(meanlog), exp(sdlog)), 
    nrow = N, ncol = 50) ### the underlying distribution of this 
               ### biomarker is lognormal, hence rlnorm here ###

data_matrix <- as.data.frame(data_matrix)

### first, count how many observations are >= 150, 
### excluding the first value ###
low_temp <- data_matrix[-c(1), ] 

df_one <- low_temp%>%
  gather(PID, value, V1:V50)%>%
  group_by(PID)%>%
  tally(value > 149, name = "low") 

### Same deal, but for >= 300 ###
high_temp <- data_matrix[-c(1), ]

df_two <- high_temp %>%
  gather(PID, value, V1:V50)%>%
  group_by(PID)%>%
  tally(value > 299, name = "high")

zero_temp <- data_matrix[-c(1), ]

df <- zero_temp %>%
  gather(PID, value, V1:V50) %>%
  group_by(PID)%>%
  tally(value >= 0, name = "total")

### now remove all but the first eosinophil readings ###
first <- data_matrix[-c(2:nrow(data_matrix)), ] 

### Convert from wide to long ###
long <- first %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = "V1":"V50",
    names_to = "PID",
    values_to = "eos"
  )

### arrange so we can join data frames easily ###
long <- long %>% arrange(PID)

### Calculate the frequency of >= 150 for each individual ###
freq_low <- cbind(df_one$low / df$total, long$eos) %>% as.data.frame()
freq_high <- cbind(df_two$high / df$total, long$eos) %>% as.data.frame()

### trusty labels ###
labels_two <- c("0-50", "51-100", "101-150", "151-200", "201-250", 
                "251-300", "301-350", "351-400", "401+")

### Now group the eos into categories ###
cat_low <- freq_low %>% mutate(
            new_bin = cut(V2, breaks=c(-1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 
                      300, 350, 400, Inf), labels = labels_two))

cat_high <- freq_high %>% mutate(
            new_bin = cut(V2, breaks=c(-1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 
                      300, 350, 400, Inf), labels = labels_two))

### calculate frequency for each group ###
final_set_low <- cat_low %>% 
  group_by(new_bin) %>% 
  summarize(mean(V1))
colnames(final_set_low) <- c("new_bin", "Any_low")

final_set_high <- cat_high %>% 
  group_by(new_bin) %>% 
  summarize(mean(V1))
colnames(final_set_high) <- c("new_bin", "Any_high")

p_one <- ggplot(data = final_set_low, 
  mapping = aes(x=new_bin, y=Any_low)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Probability that any subsequent reading is ≥150") +
  xlab("Initial PBEC Count") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))

p_two <- ggplot(data = final_set_high, 
  mapping = aes(x=new_bin, y=Any_high)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Probability that any subsequent reading is ≥300") +
  xlab("Initial PBEC Count") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))

library(egg)

grid.arrange(p_one, p_two, nrow = 1) 
## obviously this doesn't look as good, but you get the picture

#### okay this does the PCOT ###
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

temp_one = matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(data_matrix), ncol=ncol(data_matrix))
temp_two = matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(data_matrix), ncol=ncol(data_matrix))

## this might look odd, but I have some patients with 5 observations,
## some with 34. this allows me to handle the NAs in the data frame ###

for(i in 1:ncol(data_matrix)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(data_matrix)){
    if(is.na(data_matrix[j+1, i])){
      temp_one[j, i] <- NA
    } else if(data_matrix[j+1, i] >= 150){
      temp_one[j, i] <- 1
    } else if(data_matrix[j+1, i] < 149) {
      temp_one[j, i] <- 0
    } 
  }
}

for(i in 1:ncol(data_matrix)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(data_matrix)){
    if(is.na(data_matrix[j+1, i])) {
      temp_two[j, i] <- NA
    } else {
      temp_two[j, i] <- data_matrix[j, i]
    }
  }
}
temp_one_df <- as.data.frame(temp_one)
temp_two_df <- as.data.frame(temp_two)

long_one <- temp_one_df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `V1`:`V50`,
    names_to = "PID",
    values_to = "Subs"
  )

long_two <- temp_two_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `V1`:`V50`, 
    names_to = "PID",
    values_to = "EOS"
  )

long <- cbind(long_one, long_two$EOS)
colnames(long) <- c("PID", "Subs", "EOS")
long <- long %>% arrange(PID)
long <- na.omit(long)

labels <- c("0-24", "25-49", "50-74", "75-99", "100-124", 
            "125-149", "150-174", "175-199", "200-224", "225-249", 
            "250-274", "275-299", "300-324", "325-349", "350-374", 
            "375-399", "400+")

long_cat <- long %>% mutate(
    new_bin = cut(EOS, breaks=c(-1, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 
                  200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, Inf),
                  labels = labels))

final_set_low <- long_cat %>% 
  group_by(new_bin) %>% 
  summarize(prob = 
    (sum(Subs == "1") / sum(Subs == "1" | Subs == "0")))

plot_one <- ggplot(data = final_set_low, mapping = aes(x=new_bin, 
                                            y=prob)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Probability the next reading is ≥150") +
  xlab("PBEC Count") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) +
  labs(tag = "3a)") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))

plot_one



Could you please edit the question to say more about how frequently the measurements are made? In particular, are they on a regular fixed schedule or are they only made when a patient comes in with a problem? Also, it might help to say more about the second clinical threshold, and about how both thresholds are interpreted and used in practice. For example, does a level beyond one of the thresholds lead to a clinical intervention that might then affect the PBEC value?

Interesting problem, but it seems to me that once you start thinking about the probability of a measurement going on to exceed a threshold you are probably looking for prediction intervals. However, I'm not at all clear on how you would use your probability estimate. Are you thinking of a Bayesian calculation to replace the threshold? (And given the speed and ease of measuring haematocrit, would a second measurement be better than your probability calculation in practice?)

Just updated the question, thanks again for your comments
